# Vuetify form validate a custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I got a custom date picker with a nested text-field, i would like to know if there's any way to validate my component on the function this.$refs.form.validate().

My Component:

```
<template>
    <v-menu
        v-model="dateMenu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        offset-y
        max-width="290"
    >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
                prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                :label="label"
                v-on="on"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-model="dateFormatted"
                readonly
                clearable
                :rules="rules"
                :dense="dense"
            ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <template default>
            <v-date-picker
                locale="es-AR"
                v-model="date"
                no-title
            ></v-date-picker>
        </template>
    </v-menu>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a best practice to avoid using $ref as much as possible as it is manually accessing the DOM. You can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html).

I would suggest using you own code to access the data in the v-model and check your validation there, for an example:

```
// Template area
<v-text-field v-model="firstname" :rules="nameRules" label="First Name" required>
</v-text-field>

// Data area
firstname: '',
lastname: '',
nameRules: [
  v => !!v || 'Name is required',
  v => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
],
```

Comment: The "best practice" you refer to is to avoid DOM manipulation in Vue (which is exactly what the documentation states). When you do manipulate DOM, for whatever reason, the recommended way is to use `$refs`. I'd refrain from saying it is best practice to avoid using `$refs`, as it can be misinterpreted, especially by novice developers.

Comment: I agree and stand corrected. Thank you for the clarification!